count occurrences in a period of time
Good day,
I would like to count occurrences in a period of time. The periods are in minutes:
**0 - 5 minutes**;
**5:01 - 10 minutes**;
**10:01 - 15 minutes**;
**15:01 - 30 minutes**;
**>30 minutes**

The values are in a measure named TD_New-Dispatch
TD_New-Dispatch
00:03:43
00:04:12
00:01:11
00:00:26
00:02:11
00:01:13
00:01:42
00:26:49
00:26:56
00:26:22
03:26:11
00:24:09


First create a calculated column to convert the time duration into minutes:
DurationMinutes = 
VAR Hours = HOUR('Test'[TimeColumn])
VAR Minutes = MINUTE('Test'[TimeColumn])
VAR Seconds = SECOND('Test'[TimeColumn])
RETURN Hours * 60 + Minutes + Seconds / 60

Then create another CC to categorize the time into the ranges you defined :
TimeRange = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    'Test'[DurationMinutes] <= 5, "0 - 5 minutes",
    'Test'[DurationMinutes] > 5 && 'Test'[DurationMinutes] <= 10, "5:01 - 10 minutes",
    'Test'[DurationMinutes] > 10 && 'Test'[DurationMinutes] <= 15, "10:01 - 15 minutes",
    'Test'[DurationMinutes] > 15 && 'Test'[DurationMinutes] <= 30, "15:01 - 30 minutes",
    'Test'[DurationMinutes] > 30, ">30 minutes",
    "Other"
)


Then simply create a measure :
OccurrencesCount = 
COUNTROWS('Test')


